# How to change the URL category of a website, so it's not filtered

Tags: firewall, filtering, webfilter

This may be out of my control, but currently, when I try to access my website from work, I get this page:

```
Access Denied

Your system policy has denied access to the requested URL.

Monitoring of Your Internet Activity is Being Performed
Proxy IP Address:       U522XG-O2A
Exception ID:           policy_denied
URL Requested:         http://myurl.com/
URL Category:           none
Date:                   2011-03-24
```

Is there even a way that I can set the URL Category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you knew what they used for the content filtering system, you *might* be able to take action to get it categorized appropriately.

If I had to guess from the information your copy/pasted, I'd say you're working with a BlueCoat Web Filter.  Check this link to see how they've categorized your site.

http://sitereview.bluecoat.com/sitereview.jsp

Comment: Is there some kind of META code or something I can add to myself to change it's categorization?

Comment: This is a question that is specific to BlueCoat's (if that's indeed who we're dealing with) web filtering system.  I doubt they allow you to just flag yourself as whatever you wish to be seen as, after all, that would make it very easy for all webmasters to circumvent web filtering systems.  They will likely need to review the site with human eyes in order to recategorize it.

Comment: The probability of a filtering system that requires actual people to verify seems... impossible.  There are many obscure websites that I can access, that people just wouldn't find unless searching for some of the things I search for, and I'm the only person that does this particular job.  So frustrating.

Comment: I don't mean to suggest that the entire process is manual, I'm simply referring to the review process that would REcategorize a website if a webmaster chose to make a case of it.  You're right in sensing that the process of the initial categorization of sites for their filter is 99.9% automated, but they need to provide a way for webmasters to file an appeal.